# myBatis how to combine many select results to only one entity

Tags: mybatis

I have a entity : one Question has many answers.
to use JSTL show the results conveniently, I'd like to combine many select results to only one entity; just like the following:

```xml
<!-- 根据节查找 -->
  <select id="selectDetailedBySectionId" resultMap="BaseResultMap" parameterType="java.lang.Integer" >
    select 
    q.id, q.question, q.type, q.tea_id,
    a.id as ans_id, a.item as ans_item, a.isTrue as ans_isTrue
    from questions q, answers a
    where q.sec_id = #{id} and q.id = a.que_id
  </select>
```

I give a select ,it back to 4 results.so if i us  the frontPage is like this:

[image]

so is there a method to combine these entity to just one.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you want a result entity consisting in: 1 question => a collection of N answers.

You will have to use Mybatis collection mapping, [see an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13046893/7076047).